# Python web scraping page loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Appreciate this is been asked many time on here but I cant seem to get it to work for me.

I've written a scraper which successfully scrapes everything I need from the first page of the site. But, I cant figure out how to get it to loop through the various pages.

The url simply increments like this BLAH/3 + 'page=x'

I haven't been learning to code for very long, so any advice would be appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3'

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# String substitution for HTML
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
"<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

# Fetch and print general data from title class
general_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'})


for item in general_data:
    name = print(item.contents[0].text)
    address = print(item.contents[1].text.replace('.',''))
    care_type = print(item.contents[2].text)
```

Update:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3')

for page in range(10):

    r = requests.get('http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3' + 'page=' + page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())


# String substitution for HTML
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    "<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

# Fetch and print general data from title class
general_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'})


for item in general_data:
    name = print(item.contents[0].text)
    address = print(item.contents[1].text.replace('.',''))
    care_type = print(item.contents[2].text)
```

Update 2!:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3&page='

for page in range(10):

r = requests.get(url + str(page))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# String substitution for HTML
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print("<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))

# Fetch and print general data from title class
general_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'})

for item in general_data:
    print(item.contents[0].text)
    print(item.contents[1].text.replace('.',''))
    print(item.contents[2].text)
```

Comment: Take a look in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809017/scrapy-scraping-links-found-while-scraping/40810840#40810840 If this dowsn't help you let us know.

Comment: to loop you need `while` or `for` - now you don't have it.

Comment: @daniboy000 - sorry I cant seem to relate that to mine! :s

Comment: Thanks @furas. This is what I’m looking at now but cannot seem to get it to work? 


   r = requests.get(url+page)

r = requests.get('http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3?page=') # url next page

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

url = 'http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3?page='

for page in range(10): # get 10 pages

    r = requests.get(url+page)

Comment: Sorry @furas not sure how to present comments as code!

Comment: edit question and add code to question - it will be more readable.

Comment: you mess in this code in comment - first you use `get(url+page)` but you define `url=...` later. And you use `get('URL.org/..')` but you already have `get(url+page)` - it makes no sense.

Comment: better add your url to question because every page need different solution.

Comment: @furas just added to the question! Thank you again, appreciate your help!

Comment: you have wrong indentions - you read pages in for-loop but you do nothing with this pages because you have wrong indentions. Indentions are very important in Python.

Comment: @furas thank you! So with correct indentations this will work correctly? I am not sure which section has incorrect indentations?

Comment: btw: `print()` is use to send text on screen - it doesn't return text so `name = print(..)` makes no sense. You need `name = item.contents[0].text`

Comment: it seem you have to learn how `for-loop` works. Everything with indentions is part of `for-loop`. Everthing without indentions is not part of `for-loop`

Comment: @furas so indent everything in line with r = requests.get('http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3' + 'page=' + page)

Comment: you have to indent every line which you want use in loop. See indentions in new code in my answer

Comment: @furas thank you, took the comments on board and have updated in question. I watched a tutorial which stopped at the loop and didn't make any further tutorials! Unfortunately still not working? Sorry appreciate this may be frustrating but am very new to this!

Comment: I forgot that `page` is number and you have to convert it to string - `str()` - before you concatenate with url - `get(url + str(page))`

Comment: BTW: I made one mistake in code - it has to be `print(item.contents[2].text)` without `care_type = ` inside `print()`

Comment: @furas thank you, fixed the print issue and updated in the answer box again. It is the &page= followed by the number page which changes. I was thinking that may be where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop pages with `page=x` you need `for` loop like this>

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.housingcare.org/housing-care/results.aspx?ath=1%2c2%2c3%2c6%2c7&stp=1&sm=3&vm=list&rp=10&page='

for page in range(10):

    print('---', page, '---')

    r = requests.get(url + str(page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    # String substitution for HTML
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        print("<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))

    # Fetch and print general data from title class
    general_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'})

    for item in general_data:
        print(item.contents[0].text)
        print(item.contents[1].text.replace('.',''))
        print(item.contents[2].text)
```

Every page can be different and better solution needs more inforamtion about page. Sometimes you can get link to last page and then you can use this information instead `10` in `range(10)`

Or you can use `while True` to loop and `break` to leave loop if there is no link to next page. But first you have to show this page (url to real page) in question.

---

**EDIT:** example how to get link to next page and then you get all pages - not only 10 pages as in previous version.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# link to first page - without `page=`
url = 'http://www.housingcare.org/housing-care/results.aspx?ath=1%2c2%2c3%2c6%2c7&stp=1&sm=3&vm=list&rp=10'

# only for information, not used in url
page = 0 

while True:

    print('---', page, '---')

    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    # String substitution for HTML
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        print("<a href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))

    # Fetch and print general data from title class
    general_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'title'})

    for item in general_data:
        print(item.contents[0].text)
        print(item.contents[1].text.replace('.',''))
        print(item.contents[2].text)

    # link to next page

    next_page = soup.find('a', {'class': 'next'})

    if next_page:
        url = next_page.get('href')
        page += 1
    else:
        break # exit `while True`
```

Comment: better put this in question - it can be more readable and everyone will see it (and can answer)

Comment: Thanks @furas. This is what I’m looking at now but cannot seem to get it to work? 


   r = requests.get(url+page)

r = requests.get('http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3?page=') # url next page

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

url = 'http://www.URL.org/BLAH1/BLAH2/BLAH3?page='

for page in range(10): # get 10 pages

    r = requests.get(url+page)

Comment: I add example which finds link to next page and uses it instead of `for-loop`

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I just run that and it is till returning the same results from the first page? :S