# Scrape angel list profiles description using Python Beatifulsoup

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, vba

A newbie scraper here !

I am currently indulged in a tedious and boring task where I have to copy/paste certain contents from Angel List and save them in excel. I have previously used scrapers to automate such boring tasks but this one is quite tough and I am unable to find a way to automate it. Please find below the website link:

```
https://angel.co/people/all
```

Kindly apply filters **Location-> USA, and Market-> Online Dating**. There will be around 550 results (please note that the URL doesn't change when you apply the filters)

I have successfully scraped the URLs of all the profiles once filters are applied. Therefore, I have an excel file with 550 URLs of these profiles.

Now the next step is to go to individual profiles and **scrape** certain information. I am looking for these fields currently:

1. Name
2. Description Information
3. Investments
4. Founder
5. Advisor
6. Locations
7. Markets
8. What I'm looking for

Now I have tried a lot of solutions but none have worked so far. Import.io, data miner, data scraper tools are not helping me much.

Please suggest is there any VBA code or Python code or any tool that can help me to automate this scraping task?

**COMPLETE CODE FOR SOLUTION:**

Here is the final code with comments. If someone still has problems, please comment below and I will try to help you out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import json
import csv

def fetch_page(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    # changing the user agent as the default one is banned
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/43.0.1')]
    return opener.open(url).read()


#Create a CSV File.
f = open('angle_profiles.csv', 'w')
# Row Headers
f.write("URL" + "," + "Name" + "," + "Founder" + "," + "Advisor" + "," + "Employee" + "," + "Board Member" + ","
    + "Customer" + "," + "Locations" + "," + "Markets" + "," + "Investments" + "," + "What_iam_looking_for" + "\n")

# URLs to iterate over has been saved in file: 'profiles_links.csv' . I will extract the URLs individually...
index = 1;
with open("profiles_links.csv") as f2:

    for row in map(str.strip,f2):
        url = format(row)
        print "@ Index: ", index
        index += 1;

        # Check if URL has 404 error. if yes, skip and continue with the rest of URLs.
        try:
            html = fetch_page(url)
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Error 404 @: " , url
            continue

        bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        #Extract info from page with these tags..
        name = bs.select(".profile-text h1")[0].get_text().strip()

        #description = bs.select('div[data-field="bio"]')[0]['data-value']

        founder = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_founder a'))

        advisor = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_advisor a'))

        employee = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_employee a'))

        board_member = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_board_member a'))

        customer = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_customer a'))

        class_wrapper = bs.body.find('div', attrs={'data-field' : 'tags_interested_locations'})
        count = 1
        locations = {}
        
        if class_wrapper is not None:
            for span in class_wrapper.find_all('span'):
                locations[count] = span.text
                count +=1

        class_wrapper = bs.body.find('div', attrs={'data-field' : 'tags_interested_markets'})
        count = 1
        markets = {}
        if class_wrapper is not None:
            for span in class_wrapper.find_all('span'):
                markets[count] = span.text
                count +=1
        
        what_iam_looking_for = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.get_text().strip(), bs.select('div.criteria p')))

        user_id = bs.select('.profiles-show .profiles-show')[0]['data-user_id']

        # investments are loaded using separate request and response is in JSON format
        json_data = fetch_page("https://angel.co/startup_roles/investments?user_id=%s" % user_id)

        investment_records = json.loads(json_data)

        investments = map(lambda x: x['company']['company_name'], investment_records)

        # Make sure that every variable is in string

        name2 = str(name); founder2 = str(founder); advisor2 = str (advisor); employee2 = str(employee)
        board_member2 = str(board_member); customer2 = str(customer); locations2 = str(locations); markets2 = str (markets);
        what_iam_looking_for2 = str(what_iam_looking_for); investments2 = str(investments);

        # Replace any , found with - so that csv doesn't confuse it as col separator...
        name = name2.replace(",", " -")
        founder = founder2.replace(",", " -")
        advisor = advisor2.replace(",", " -")
        employee = employee2.replace(",", " -")
        board_member = board_member2.replace(",", " -")
        customer = customer2.replace(",", " -")
        locations = locations2.replace(",", " -")
        markets = markets2.replace(",", " -")
        what_iam_looking_for = what_iam_looking_for2.replace(","," -")
        investments = investments2.replace(","," -")

        # Replace u' with nothing
        name = name.replace("u'", "")
        founder = founder.replace("u'", "")
        advisor = advisor.replace("u'", "")
        employee = employee.replace("u'", "")
        board_member = board_member.replace("u'", "")
        customer = customer.replace("u'", "")
        locations = locations.replace("u'", "")
        markets = markets.replace("u'", "")
        what_iam_looking_for = what_iam_looking_for.replace("u'", "")
        investments = investments.replace("u'", "")

        # Write the information back to the file... Note \n is used to jump one row ahead...
        f.write(url + "," + name + "," + founder + "," + advisor + "," + employee + "," + board_member + ","
                + customer + "," + locations + "," + markets + "," + investments + "," + what_iam_looking_for + "\n")
```

Feel free to test the above code with any of the following links:

```
https://angel.co/idg-ventures?utm_source=people
https://angel.co/douglas-feirstein?utm_source=people
https://angel.co/andrew-heckler?utm_source=people
https://angel.co/mvklein?utm_source=people
https://angel.co/rajs1?utm_source=people
```

HAPPY CODING :)

Comment: You can use python scrapy https://scrapy.org/ to do this task. Take a look in this answer to see how can you get info from multiple data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809017/scrapy-scraping-links-found-while-scraping/40810840#40810840

Comment: @daniboy000 It is quite difficult to understand as I have taken only few tutorials of Python and I have zero experience with Scrapy.

Comment: The scrapy documentation is pretty good and in the second example they show to you how to do what you want.

Comment: @halfer thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my recipe you will need to install BeautifulSoup using pip or easy_install

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import json

def fetch_page(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    # changing the user agent as the default one is banned
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    return opener.open(url).read()


html = fetch_page("https://angel.co/davidtisch")

# or load from local file
#html = open('page.html', 'r').read()

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
name = bs.select(".profile-text h1")[0].get_text().strip()

description = bs.select('div[data-field="bio"]')[0]['data-value']

founder = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_founder a'))

advisor = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('.role_advisor a'))

locations = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('div[data-field="tags_interested_locations"] a'))

markets = map(lambda link: link.get_text().strip(), bs.select('div[data-field="tags_interested_markets"] a'))

what_iam_looking_for = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.get_text().strip(), bs.select('div.criteria p')))

user_id = bs.select('.profiles-show .profiles-show')[0]['data-user_id']

# investments are loaded using separate request and response is in JSON format
json_data = fetch_page("https://angel.co/startup_roles/investments?user_id=%s" % user_id)

investment_records = json.loads(json_data)

investments = map(lambda x: x['company']['company_name'], investment_records)
```

Comment: Hi. Installed BS4, figured out how to save data in csv file and iterate over 550 URLs as well. 
Just one thing remaining: **description** is giving error. AND **locations & market** fields are null. Please suggest, after that the task will be complete. And thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfanAli all the fields can be extracted using several different ways. The expressions I gave work for the 2 users I tried. If you still have difficulties with some fields just give me the url for which my code doesn't work and I will try to fix it.

Comment: I have updated the post. Please review. description is not important. locations and markets are mandatory fields so if these can be extracted, it will be great. Right now I am getting [].

Comment: Please let me know if you are able to achieve it because I have tried using **bs.find_all(<div class="value" data-field="tags_interested_locations">)** and still the response is []. If you are able to do it, please let me know otherwise I might post it as a separate question. thanks.

Comment: Hi, I was able to successfully extract the required fields. In the post you can find the complete solution. Please feel free to suggest :)

Comment: @MuhammadIrfanAli I tried my oneliner for locations and it works perfectly with each of your links too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://scrapy.org/

It allows write parser very quickly. Here's my example parser for one site alike angel.co: https://gist.github.com/lisitsky/c4aac52edcb7abfd5975be067face1bb

Unfortunately, angel.co is not available for me now. Good point to start:

```
$ pip install scrapy
$ cat > myspider.py <<EOF

import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://angel.co']

    def parse(self, response):
        # here's selector to extract interesting elements
        for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            # write down here values you'd like to extract from the element
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        # how to find next page
        next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)

EOF

$ scrapy runspider myspider.py
```

Enter interesting css-selectors and run spider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since I am new to Python it will take me a lot of time to write the code. Can you please provide a working sample for angle.co with comments so that I can understand what it does.

Comment: I've updated reply. Just insert right CSS-selectors.